# About SSL Cert conflict

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I wanna ask about ssl conflict issue for service
I already have wild-card domain certificate which includes *.server.com,server.com and using this domain for the service

And I'm considering about attaching new service
This new service requires wildcard domain and base domain
So I want to use new wild certificate for drive.server.com, *.drive.server.com

In this case
Is there a conflict with (*.server.com,server.com wildcard-cert) and (*.drive.server.com,drive.server.com wildcard-cert)?
As I know it doesn't conflict with *.server.com and *.drive.server.com

But drive.server.com and *.server.com which certificate I should use for service?
Doesn't it conflict between them?

Comment: You need a multi-domain wildcard SSL certificate.

Comment: To answer your question, in theory there is nothing wrong with buying 2 standard wildcard SSL certificates and targeting `*.server.com` and `*.drive.server.com`. It will not conflict because `*.server.com` will never match to `*.drive.server.com` or vice versa.